# OpenCL Error -1001 / gr-fosphor with Intel CPU OpenCL

Tags: linux, opencl, fft, gnuradio, ld-preload

### Error

```
[!] CL Error (-1001, cl.c:286): Unable to fetch platform IDs
[!] No suitable OpenCL device found
[!] Failed to initialize fosphor
```

### Conext

I installed `gr-fosphor` according to https://osmocom.org/projects/sdr/wiki/Fosphor on `Linux Mint 20.3 x64 Cinnamon` with `Intel CPU OpenCL`.

```sh
# Install Dependencies
sudo apt-get install cmake xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libspdlog-dev

# Install OpenCL depending on platform and hardware configuration
# Intel CPU OpenCL: Intel Core i5-3570K
# https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases
cd ~
mkdir intel-opencl
cd intel-opencl
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/22.06.22433/intel-gmmlib_22.0.2_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/intel-graphics-compiler/releases/download/igc-1.0.10183/intel-igc-core_1.0.10183_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/intel-graphics-compiler/releases/download/igc-1.0.10183/intel-igc-opencl_1.0.10183_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/22.06.22433/intel-opencl-icd_22.06.22433_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/22.06.22433/intel-level-zero-gpu_1.3.22433_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/22.06.22433/ww06.sum
sha256sum -c ww06.sum
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

# Build Dependceny GLFW
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/glfw/glfw
cd glfw
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../ -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=true
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig

# Install gr-fosphor
cd ~
git clone git://git.osmocom.org/gr-fosphor
cd gr-fosphor
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig

# Try to run fosphor
cd ~
cd gr-fosphor/lib/fosphor
./main  # CL Error / Unable to fetch platform IDs

# Make fosphor with platform and hardware-specific OpenCL LDFLAGS
cd ~
cd gr-fosphor/lib/fosphor
# platform's OpenCL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/intel-opencl/libigdrcl.so
make clean
make LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/intel-opencl

# Try to run fosphor
cd ~
cd gr-fosphor/lib/fosphor
./main  # Still CL Error / Unable to fetch platform IDs

# Try the LD_PRELOAD trick
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so"

# Try to run fosphor
cd ~
cd gr-fosphor/lib/fosphor
./main  # CL Error / Unable to fetch platform IDs
```

### Libs loaded

```sh
# Unset Preloading of `libOpenCL.so`
unset LD_PRELOAD

# `libOpenCL.so` is found by `fosphor` when it's not preloaded
ldd main        
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffda32dc000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f8cb1ec0000)
    libglfw.so.3 => /usr/local/lib/libglfw.so.3 (0x00007f8cb1e49000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8cb1cfa000)
    libOpenCL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so.1 (0x00007f8cb1aef000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f8cb1a67000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8cb1a61000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8cb186d000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f8cb1835000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8cb1819000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8cb17f6000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8cb1fd8000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f8cb173e000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f8cb170a000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f8cb15cb000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f8cb15a1000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f8cb159b000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f8cb1593000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f8cb1579000)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Installing Intel's `beignet-opencl-icd` fixed the problem, as it is required to initialize OpenCL devices.

```
sudo apt install ocl-icd-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1 beignet-opencl-icd
sudo ~/gr-fosphor/lib/fosphor/main  # Try running it as sudo once
```